# How to make socket.io listen to event when controller/view changes (angular js)

Tags: angularjs, socket.io

here is my controller

```
angular
.module('hoApp')
.controller('adminmapCtrl', adminmapCtrl);

function adminmapCtrl ($scope,socket) {
    $scope.positions = []; 
    socket.on('client', function(data) {
      $scope.$apply(function(){
        $scope.client = data;
      });
    });

    socket.on('positions', function(data) {
        $scope.$apply(function(){
            $scope.positions.push(data);
        });
    });

}
```

my problem is once i change the controller/view socket.io stops listening to event i want socket to keep listening to event so i can get the new values of positions and client when i come back to the controller/view

```
  angular
    .module('hoApp')
    .factory('socket', socket);

  function socket ($rootScope) {
      var socket = io.connect('http://127.0.0.1:3000');
      return {
        on: function(eventName, callback){
          socket.on(eventName, callback);
        },
        emit: function(eventName, data) {
          socket.emit(eventName, data);
        }
      };
  }
```

here is my socket service

Comment: Can you post the code for your socket service?

Comment: here is my socket service

Comment: i have made changes to my code please someone should give me a solution .